# How to combine multiple tables and allow a "like" text search option for filtering, including if the criteria was left blank

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 different tables where I want to be able to combine them and then filter them based off of 4 different inputs OR LESS on a search. I also would like to have it work when some filters are none.. Here is the breakdown what I mean:

[image]

So above there are three tables with column names and some data. NOTE: Table 1 has a comma in the location and I will want to separate those as two separate column for searching purposes which I figured out how to do.

Now What the final table I want is:

```
                          Table 1
      ------------------------------------------------
      date      city      state      title     summary
      jan 1     stl        MO         Book     
      jan 1     ATL        MO         Comp      
      Jan 1               Maine       Phone     box device
      March2               MO         Howey     weird name
      JUL2                            cheese
```

Now My goal is trying to do a text search such as what follows: The 4 criteria of filtering will be State, Title, Date, OR a keyword

I think the solution has involves joining the tables, splitting the comma, using "where true" and having some type of IF statement.

```
select
    date1,
    split_part(location1, ',', 1) as city,
    split_part(location1, ',', 2) as state,
    title1
from
    table1
```

Now I use join or union or something to add other tables?

Note:  Null means user didn't have input at all

Example 1: If Date is Jan 1, state is null, title is null, Keyword is null (it should show everything with jan1st)

Example 2: If Date is Jan 1 AND City is stl (show first row), title and keyword is null

Example 3: If Date = Jan 1 and State is MO (Show row 1,2, and 4), title and keyword is null

Last example: if Keyword is Phone and everything else is null it shows row 3.

Is there a way to do this in Postgressql? It also would be convenient if the user didnt spell a state right but still pulled up similar results. Basically I will have a interface where a user will select a date, or title and/or state, or maybe just use a key word to filter the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first task is to build a combined view of the tables involved supplying null for each that does not exit in a particular table. The following uses a CTE consisting of union of the 3 tables to accomplish that.

```
with combined as
     (Select date1                         as con_date
           , split_part(location1, ',', 1) as city
           , split_part(location1, ',', 2) as state 
           , title1                        as title
           , null                          as summary
        from table_1
        union all 
        select date2
             , state
             , null
             , title2
             , null 
          from table_2
        union all 
        select date3
             , null
             , null
             , title
             , null 
          from table_3          
      )
 select * from combined;
```

From there you can build a VIEW using the above then construct an appropriate query for the entered parameters. An alternative is a function that returns a table as below.

```
create or replace function search_combined(
                           search_date_in  date  default null
                         , search_title_in text  default null
                         , search_state_in text  default null
                         , search_word_in  text  default null
                         )
returns table (con_date date
              , city    text
              , state   text
              , title   text
              , summary text
              )
language sql
as $$
with combined as
     (Select date1                         as con_date
           , split_part(location1, ',', 1) as city
           , split_part(location1, ',', 2) as state 
           , title1                        as title
           , null                          as summary
        from table_1
        union all 
        select date2
             , state
             , null
             , title2
             , null 
          from table_2
        union all 
        select date3
             , null
             , null
             , title
             , null 
          from table_3          
      ) 
select *
  from combined
 where 1=1
   and (con_date = search_date_in or search_date_in is null)
   and (state = search_state_in or search_state_in is null)
   and (title = search_title_in or search_title_in is null) 
   and (title = search_word_in  or search_word_in is null); 
  $$; 



  -- Test 
  select  search_combined(search_date_in => date '2019-01-01');
  or 
  select  *  
    from  search_combined(search_date_in => date '2019-01-01');

  select  *  
    from  search_combned(search_date_in => date '2019-01-01'
                         ,search_state_in => 'Mo'
                         );

 select  *  
    from  search_combined( search_word_in => 'Phone');
```

The above should work as is, but I have not tested it as your sample data is a picture. In the future please provide sample data as text; as that allows copy/past to build it locally.